# Why React component infinitely updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, use-effect

I have very simple component, but for some reason it infinitely updated updated and updated. I not change anything but react update component. Why?

My action:

```
export function getMouseMenuButtons() {

    const a = {
        bold: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'bold',
            children: {
                bold: {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'bold',
                },
                calendar: {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'calendar'
                },
            }
        },
    }

    return {
        type: MOUSE_MENU_BUTTONS_GET,
        payload: a
    }
}
```

My reducer:

```
export default function (state={}, action: any) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case MOUSE_MENU_BUTTONS_GET:
            return {...state, map: action.payload};
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

And my component

```
const MenuCircles = (props: Props) => {


    useEffect(() => {
        props.dispatch(getMouseMenuButtons())
    }, [props.buttons]);




    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            dfdf
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

function mapStateToProps(state: State) {
    const buttons = state.mouseMenu && state.mouseMenu.map;

    return { buttons };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MenuCircles);
```

Why it always update. In useEffect I check props.buttons. They are always same

Comment: it means your reducer composes new array in `mouseMenu` each time action is dispatched. `useEffect` checks dependencies by reference so it's new on each re-render.

Comment: Thank you. added a reducer code, it is standard. How do I solve the reboot problem?

Answer (score 1):

So since you are construct referentially new object in action and add it unconditionally in reducer you are getting brand new `state.mouseMenu` on each run.

The easiest way to solve this is move object declaration out of action creator:

```
const defaultButtons = {
    bold: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'bold',
        children: {
            bold: {
                id: 1,
                name: 'bold',
            },
            calendar: {
                id: 2,
                name: 'calendar'
            },
        }
    },
};
export function getMouseMenuButtons() {
    return {
        type: MOUSE_MENU_BUTTONS_GET,
        payload: defaultButtons
    }
}
```

This way you will have referentially the same buttons set after action is dispatched.

Comment: but if I get data from a real API, I will do it in action. what to do then?

Comment: then your code does not make sense to me. why do we need to wait if some data has been changed to load exact same data? if it's not kind of "reset to initial" then we probably need to put some other things into dependency(I don't know, may be some `id`?)

Comment: In this component, I often change properties (others, not buttons) and therefore it will be often rendered, but I want to extract data from the api only once. I want the useEffect to work only once, and not turn to api with each renderer. Or am I mistaken in the concept?

Comment: call to API - what does it depend on? is there really no dependencies for call?

Comment: only one dependency, if the component is rendered for the first time, I need to get these buttons, like ComponentDidMount. if the component is rendered, it is necessary that api is not called

Comment: then just pass `[]` as dependencies

Comment: thank you. It works. But one more question, what if from time to time buttons changed. And api return new data. How can i update them in component